# Rails 4 Ajax like button failing to wоrk

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, social-media-like

Im struggling to make my Like links to work with ajax. After clicking on "Like" nothing changes, only after refreshing the page I can see that like got counted.

EDIT: Addet routes.
EDIT2: I inspected the Like link with Firebug and after entering the code from like.js.erb file it shows message:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fTkN.png)
My like.js.erb file:

```
        <% if Like.find_by(likeable: @post) %>
          $(".likes").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/unlike' ) %>");
        <% else %>
          $(".likes").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/like' ) %>");
        <% end %>
```

(I have checked and If conditions works fine).
My partial for posts (_post.html.erb).

```
    <li class="post">
        <span class="user"><%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %></span>
        <br>
        <span class="title"><%= post.title %></span>
        <br>
        <span class="ava"><%= image_tag post.avatar(:large) %></span>
        <br>
        <span class="timestamp">
            Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.
            <% if logged_in? && current_user.admin? %>
                <%= link_to "delete", post, method: :delete,
                                                                        data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
            <% end %>
################## START OF THE LIKES #####################
            <span class="likes">
                <span class="like">
                <% if logged_in? %>
                    <% if !current_user.likes?(current_user, post) %>
                        <%= render 'posts/like', post: post %>
                        <!-- <%= link_to "Like", like_post_path(post, like: true), method: 'post', remote: true %> -->
                    </span>
                    <% else %>
                    <span class="unlike">
                        <%= render 'posts/unlike', post: post %>
                        <!-- <%= link_to "Unlike", like_post_path(post, like: false), method: 'post', remote: true %>-->
                    </span>
                    <% end %>
                    (<%= pluralize( post.likes.size, "like") %>)
                <% else %>
                    <%= link_to "Like", login_path,
                          data: { confirm: "You need to log in to like" } %>
                    (<%= pluralize( post.likes.size, "like") %>)
                <% end %>
            </span>
################## THE END OF THE LIKES #####################
        </span>
    </li>
```

And the like method in the post controller.

```
def like
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if Like.find_by(likeable: post)
        Like.find_by(likeable: post).destroy
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html do
                flash[:success] = "Like Updated!"
                redirect_to :back
            end
            format.js
            end
    else
        Like.create(likeable: post, user: current_user, like: params[:like])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html do
                flash[:success] = "Like Updated!"
                redirect_to :back
            end
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

And Like and Unlike partials I use:
Like:

```
<%= link_to "Like", like_post_path(post, like: true), method: 'post', remote: true %>
```

Unlike:

```
<%= link_to "Like", like_post_path(post, like: false), method: 'post', remote: true %>
```

Any help or advice would be nice. I know that my code is rather in bad condition so don't be afraid to suggest some changes in it. And finally Please help me, I have wasted tons of time on trying to make it work but no results yet.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'main_page#home'
    get         'top_list'  => 'main_page#top_list'
    get         'sign_up'   => 'users#new'
    get         'posts/new'
    get         'login'         => 'sessions#new'
    post        'login'         => 'sessions#create'
    delete  'logout'        => 'sessions#destroy'
    resources :users
    resources :posts do
        member do
            post 'like'
        end
    end
end
```

There are logs after I click on Like.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 41.0ms)

NameError (undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007f8ce976ff48>:0x007f8ce976f3e0>):
  app/views/posts/_unlike.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts__unlike_html_erb___187529012528174235_70121703666860'
  app/views/posts/like.js.erb:4:in `_app_views_posts_like_js_erb__3375438513772599537_70121703368540'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:38:in `like'
```

Comment: Would you add your routes too?  It's weird that that like.js.erb is not compiling the erb.  Try to put a `<% raise %>` in that template and see if you can get it to raise.  Also, if you haven't tried - better_errors gem is a great way to help debug

Comment: One note - I checked and after changing $(".likes").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/unlike' ) %>"); to  $(".likes").html("foobar"); It actually normally changes to foobar so I am not sure if this error is the source of the problem. And yes - adding <% raise %> to like and unlike partials both raise an error. On the other hand adding it to js.erb file does not raise - but I am not sure if It should.

Comment: Additionally better_errors gem shows nothing - it does not raise any errors.

Comment: You should see an error (at least in the logs) with raise in the js.erb file.

Comment: Well I fell bad now for not thinking of that. I edited the question above and added logs. Looks like the partial does not see the variable, but I can't see why - I pass it <%= render 'posts/like', post: post %>. Any suggestions?

Comment: `post = Post.find(params[:id])` should be `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` ?  You'll need that to be an @ variable to get to the partial.

Comment: Thank You, That was the problem - could I give you credit for Your help in any way? Because I can;t upvote these comments sadly.

Comment: That's OK.  But, was it a problem with html_safe?  I've never needed to use that.

Comment: Not - this was fault of lack of post: @post in js.erb render file and not setting post to instance variable with @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `html_safe` at the end.  Also, I think render needs `post` as well (like you do in views)

```
$(".likes").html('<%= escape_javascript(render "posts/unlike",post: @post).html_safe %>');
```

http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe

Comment: Tried it and sadly it didn't solve the problem, but I really appreciate Your time and help.

Comment: Hmm, did you try using `raw` as well? and replacing `"` with `'`?

Comment: Well I needed to clean up some mess in my controller and use Your suggestion. Thank You very much!